# How can we allow a particular User UID to have only access to a particular collection in Firestore security rules?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I would like to explain my problem with an example ;There is a user having  uid [let say: vluAZiiV3deiFaPq5KdzFI1Dsx73] should only be given access to a collection [let say: elephant] out of three collections elephant,tiger,cheetah.

I tried to write the following rule to best of my knowledge but It didn't work.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /elephant/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == AZiiV3deiFaPq5KdzFI1Dsx73
    }
 }}
```

Comment: What didn't work? Please include the code that you tried against these rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The app is crashing everytime the user with above uid tries to login. P.S. : There is no error in my login activity and my app was working perfectly before implementing these rules. I havn't use any code against these rules, I have only used above four lines to implement the query

Comment: Shouldn't it be `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == "AZiiV3deiFaPq5KdzFI1Dsx73"`, i.e. the uid value declared as a string?

Comment: Oh wow, did the editor accept that without quotes around it? Well, I guess it could be a variable/path segment name, but I'd expect a warning at least in that case. :-/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, The editor accepted uid without quotes and havn't shown any warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the `uid` value as string, with quotes, as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /elephant/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == "AZiiV3deiFaPq5KdzFI1Dsx73"
    }
 }}
```